# Quotient of two metrics on a non empty set $X$ is again a metric or not.

Tags: metric-spaces

Quotient of two metrics on a non empty set $X$ is again a metric or not.

My Attempt:

Case (i) If I take $d$ as $d(x,y) = \frac{d_1(x,y)}{d_2(x,y)}$ then $d$ is not well defined as $d(x,y) \geq 0$

Case(ii) If I take $d$ as
$d(x,y) = \frac{d_1}{d_2}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}\frac{d_1(x,y)}{d_2(x,y)}, &\text{if }x \neq y \\
0, &\text{if }x=y.
\end{cases}$ then it is well defined.

Here we see clearly that

(1) $d(x,y) \geq 0$, $\forall x,y \in X$

(2) $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y, \forall x,y \in X$

(3) $d(x,y) = d(y,x), \forall x,y \in X$

But I have faced a problem in  triangle inequality. Please help me by giving some hints or counter examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider $\Bbb R$ with discrete metric divided by standard metric.

Comment: Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two metrics on a non empty set $X$ then we work on $X$ at which $d$ defined. I'm saying that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are defined on same set $X$ but you let $d_1$ on $\Bbb R$ and $d_2$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @SangamAcademy Why do you say above answer uses two sets? I see only one set $\mathbb R$ with say $d_1$ the discrete metric and $d_2$ the standard metric.

Comment: Is usual metric called standard metric ?

Comment: Yes, usual also called standard.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a space consisting of 3 points: $X=\{a,b,c\}$.  Let:\begin{eqnarray*}d_1(a,b)&=&d_1(b,c)=d_1(a,c)=1,\\
d_2(a,b)&=&d_2(b,c)=1,\qquad d_2(a,c)=\frac13.
\end{eqnarray*}

Both $d_1,d_2$ make $X$ a metric space.  However the quotient you defined does not satisfy the triangle inequality as : $1+1<3$

Comment: I could not understand what you say. Please elaborate it.

Comment: Elaborated     now.